# Static and media files are not working on django real server

Tags: django, server, django-staticfiles

In the result (real server) the css, js and images are not connected, but the thing is that in localhost it works perfect. I dont know what any other details do you need so write comment and I will edit this queston :)

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'uni_form'
LOGIN_URL = ''
```

Comment: you should refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: If you refer to the link in the above comment by OlegT you will find out Django does not serve static files in production. You need to serve them separately.

Comment: anything about settings?

Comment: @BareTalk Why are you fixated on the settings, when you have `DEBUG = False` in your settings it means you are on a _"real server"_ also called a production server, in this scenario Django will **not** serve your static / media files (inefficient), hence please refer the above link.

Comment: try to  run collectstatic

Comment: it returns a traceback

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you **misconfigured** *nginx* file or did not mention in *nginx* file.

You need to write path in nginx file something like below:

```
location static_url {
        alias   static_dir
    }
```

Comment: i am sure that problem is with settings

Comment: Which server you are using?

Comment: vps ssh from reg.ru